# Looping through ArrayList after updating values with array Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I am looking for help with a portion of my program. I was wondering how I can loop through the entire "students" ArrayList before removing or keeping the "student" in the ArrayList. The updateStatus method parameter is an int and returns a boolean: true if the student has the required amount of credits to graduate, and false if they don't have enough. If you would like me to post my code for the updateStatus (which I know work 100% accurately), I can do so.

Here is the for-loop I am having an issue with:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();        
int [] updates = {4, 7, 8, 6, 15, 10, 30, 31, 5, 7, 127, 21}; //this is the array of values being input to updateStatus

for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
    for(Student x: students){
        if(x.updateStatus(updates[i])){
            System.out.println(students.remove(i)+"\nCongratulations Graduate!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: As you look through the list, use another List to add the students you want removed to. You could split the list into two lists (keep/remove) or simply remove the “to remove” items directly from the original list

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it

Comment: Is your double for loop intentional?  Do you really want to call updateStatus 12 times for each student, passing the same set of 12 data items to each student?

Comment: The relationship between `updates` and `updateStatus` is unclear. Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 2):

---

It seems your array of ints contains all the credits each student has. Student x has 4 credits, next student has 7 credits, etc. If that is true, calling it updates makes absolutely no sense. Name your variables more appropriately, otherwise, this example is sure hard to follow. Why not associate the credits with the Student object and while looping through you call a method like *getCredits()* to check their credits. In addition, inside your student object you could have a field *isGraduate* that's a boolean and says whether the student qualifies for graduation or not. This value is checked everytime a student earns credits.. so it checks periodically.

This code is very confusing, you're looping the number of students while looping the number of students... You can't do that.

Also, it seems you are calling a method name *.remove* inside your output. No idea what this method does but I don't see a case where this should be placed inside a *System.out.println*... if the method removes the student from the list, this is going to severally mess up your loop and cause problems.

It's not clear what your goal is and if you're not sure what you're trying to achieve no one here is going to be able to help you, unfortunately.